# SOAP webservice with spyne, django and apache

Tags: django, apache, web, service, spyne

I have a django based website deployed with apache and mod_wsgi.
I need to develop a SOAP based webservice and to host it with my django project, using the same port (80).

So I've read about spyne:
http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/02_helloworld.html?highlight=django
Seems like it fits my needs. I just couldn't find how to deploy it with apache.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you are going to need to end up with:

```
...

application = WsgiApplication(app)
```

That is, a WSGI script file which constructs your application and exposes it as `application` and not `wsgi_app` as the docs say to use.

Then configure mod_wsgi something like:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess soapapp
WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /some/path/soapapp.wsgi \
    process-group=soapapp application-group=%{GLOBAL}

<Directory /some/path/>
<Files soapapp.wsgi>
# Order allow,deny
# Allow from all
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

That is, create a separate daemon process group for this application. Mount it at a sub URL and delegate it to run in the separate daemon process group rather than in whatever process your Django application is. Also ensure you set up access rights so Apache knows it is allow to host the WSGI application from where it exists.

You would then access the SOAP service at that sub URL.

Comment: Django transport is needed if the Spyne app needs to be integrated with Django's url routing. That way, the Spyne app can be used without changing anything in the mod_wsgi side. If that's not needed, the Spyne app can be exported as a separate Wsgi application, which in turn can be exported using a separate entry in the mod_wsgi configuration as Graham shows here.